# Button On press is working only on certain areas of the button in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, reactive-programming

Hi Everyone,
            I am fetching a few buttons from an API and displaying them in a view according to their names. Each of them is displayed as

```
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.onBtnClick.bind(this, item.apiurl)} > 
<Text style={styles.Text}{item.displayName}</Text>                    
</TouchableHighlight>
```

The button click is not working all over the button except for the last one. It only works on specific areas. I have modified UI is several ways for the first few and checked. It still remains the same. 
     Any suggestions/Improvements are appreciated.

Comment: Have you got a solution to this? I encountered the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're binding the `onBtnClick` function everytime you click your button.

Simple fix would be `onPress={() => this.onBtnClick(item.apiurl)`

Comment: Thank you for your help @KeenyNguyen. But, it still stays the same. The button is not responsive once I give some styling to it. The first few buttons stay unresponsive while the last button is perfectly responsive. Please help me with this.

Comment: @Tholle can u have a look at this and suggest me?